# How to connect firebase functions to a Cloud SQL instance in another project?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

I have a Cloud SQL Postgres instance running in Project A. The Firebase Cloud Functions in Project A are able to connect to the Cloud SQL instance via unix sockets (i.e. `/cloudsql/project-a:region:instance-name`).

However, I also wish to connect Project B's Cloud Functions to this Cloud SQL instance, but when it tries to connect it reports `ECONNREFUSED`.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do a few things to get this working:

In the projects that I want to be able to connect to the Cloud SQL instance:

1. Enable the SQL Admin API: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/sqladmin.googleapis.com
2. Enable the Compute Engine API: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/compute.googleapis.com

In the project where the Cloud SQL instance is hosted add the "Default App Engine service account" principals for the other projects, with the role Cloud SQL Client:

[image]